# Why does my Android build always attempt to download camera-mlkit-vision-1.3.0-rc01.pom etc

Tags: android, android-build

My android builds downloads section shows the multiple attempts are always made to download the following

why does it do this for every build?
how do i stop this behaviour?

[image]

why does maven repo show 1.3.0-rc01 as a managed dep for camera2?

[image]

**UPDATE**

executing the gradlew dependencies command gives this output

```
|    +--- androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.3.0-rc01
|    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0 -> 1.6.0 (*)
|    |    +--- androidx.camera:camera-core:1.3.0-rc01
|    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0 -> 1.6.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.1.0 -> 1.3.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.1.0 -> 1.10.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.1.0 -> 2.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0 -> 9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava
|    |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.3.0-rc01 (c)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.3.0-rc01 (c)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.3.0-rc01 (c)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.camera:camera-mlkit-vision:1.3.0-rc01 -> 1.3.0-beta02 (c)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.camera:camera-video:1.3.0-rc01 (c)
|    |    |    \--- androidx.camera:camera-view:1.3.0-rc01 (c)
|    |    +--- androidx.camera:camera-core:1.3.0-rc01 (c)
|    |    +--- androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.3.0-rc01 (c)
|    |    +--- androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.3.0-rc01 (c)
|    |    +--- androidx.camera:camera-mlkit-vision:1.3.0-rc01 -> 1.3.0-beta02 (c)
|    |    +--- androidx.camera:camera-view:1.3.0-rc01 (c)
|    |    \--- androidx.camera:camera-video:1.3.0-rc01 (c)
|    +--- androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.3.0-rc01
|    |    +--- androidx.camera:camera-core:1.3.0-rc01 (*)
|    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0 -> 2.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0 -> 9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava
|    |    +--- androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.3.0-rc01 (c)
|    |    +--- androidx.camera:camera-core:1.3.0-rc01 (c)
|    |    +--- androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.3.0-rc01 (c)
|    |    +--- androidx.camera:camera-mlkit-vision:1.3.0-rc01 -> 1.3.0-beta02 (c)
|    |    +--- androidx.camera:camera-view:1.3.0-rc01 (c)
|    |    \--- androidx.camera:camera-video:1.3.0-rc01 (c)
|    +--- androidx.camera:camera-view:1.3.0-rc01
|    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0 -> 1.6.0 (*)
|    |    +--- androidx.camera:camera-core:1.3.0-rc01 (*)
|    |    +--- androidx.camera:camera-video:1.3.0-rc01
|    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0 -> 1.6.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.camera:camera-core:1.3.0-rc01 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.3.0-rc01 (c)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.camera:camera-core:1.3.0-rc01 (c)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.3.0-rc01 (c)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.3.0-rc01 (c)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.camera:camera-mlkit-vision:1.3.0-rc01 -> 1.3.0-beta02 (c)
|    |    |    \--- androidx.camera:camera-view:1.3.0-rc01 (c)
```

Im not sure what this means...

```
+--- androidx.camera:camera-mlkit-vision:1.3.0-rc01 -> 1.3.0-beta02 (c)
```

How do i stop my build trying to use a non existent version of `camera-mlkit-vision`

Answer (score 2):

There is no 1.3.0-rc01 version of that artifact, which you can tell from the "Failed" status messages.

There are multiple places where you can check it:

1. The [CameraX lib page](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera):
   [image]
2. The [Google Maven camera repo](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#androidx.camera:camera-mlkit-vision):
   as you can see, the latest available version is 1.3.0-beta02.

Changing your dependency version to 1.3.0-beta02 for the `camera-mlkit-vision` will make Gradle download the correct artifact once.

Comment: indeed, which is weird as my gradle build file only mentions the 1.3.0-beta02 version, what could have a deps for a non existent version of mlkit?

Comment: @Hector You can use `.\gradlew app:dependencies` to list the dependencies of the project (or if you have it in a different module, replace the `app` with the module name).

Comment: it appears the associated camera dependencies require a non existent version of camera-mlkit-vision '@Gergely Kőrössy'

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after updating to CameraX `1.3.0`. Although I explicitly use version `1.3.0-beta02` of `camera-mlkit-vision`, Gradle tries to download the nonexistent version `1.3.0`. My `gradle/libs.versions.toml` looks like this:

```ini
[versions]
androidx-camerax = "1.3.0"

[libraries]
androidx-camera-camera2 = { module = "androidx.camera:camera-camera2", version.ref = "androidx-camerax" }
androidx-camera-lifecycle = { module = "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle", version.ref = "androidx-camerax" }
androidx-camera-view = { module = "androidx.camera:camera-view", version.ref = "androidx-camerax" }
androidx-camera-mlkit-vision = "androidx.camera:camera-mlkit-vision:1.3.0-beta02"
```

I added the following snippet to the root `build.gradle.kts` to fix this:

```
allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force(libs.androidx.camera.mlkit.vision)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Google is working to release v1.3.1 with the coming December release since they forgot it with v1.3.0 according to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/312677260